# Opening\closing instance of object using objective c for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova

I created plugin from Html to objective-c, from changing tab in My I phone-Html project,by clicing on a tab calling plugin for iphone to start some method. i am using that code:

```
mypic *mypic= [[mypicalloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,45, 282, 282)];
    [[self.webView superview] addSubview:mypic];
    [mypicrelease];
```

what i am getting is my object (picture) over a page,but  when i continue to another tab the picture doesn't disappear,and always stays on other pages,over them. my questions is:

How can i hide\close it when changing tab and how to combine it with HTML page so the pic would start with my HTML page in 50%-50% Proportion and disappear when changing page.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a "mypic" object (and I suppose it's an imageView with an image) to your webView, you just add a child view to a parent one, so the image will always stay there. You are not adding content into webview, you are just adding a layer on another layer. Do a kind of this instead - load your webWiew with html:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <img border="0" src="URL TO YOUR IMAGE"  width="bla-bla" height="bla-bla" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no i cant get it with html its actually not simple image, its object with animation and sound(with methods)... in this example i presented it as an image but i need to control it over native layer.

Comment: In this case, you should declare a an ivar (or property, whatever) for your imageView that you present on the webView. When you are on the page where the image should be seen, set it visible, when you go to another page/tab, say [myImageViewIVar setHidden:YES]; or [self.myImageViewPropery setHidden:YES];

Comment: Sorry for the understanding...i am changing html pages with tabs on the javascript files, when i going to Mytab i am starting a method of plugin on the js file, so where should i call this Hidden?

Comment: you navigate away from the page with the image, right? so you must somehow catch this event, right? there must be an action like goToNextPage, or goToSettingsPage, whatever you name them. well, in that method (that handlers your action) hide/show the imageView, depending on where you are. if the action is performed by a javascript function, search the web how to handle javascript events in objective c, and here is your event where the changes are to be done

Answer (score 0):

Connect a method to the tab changing, create the instance in the `@interface` and in the method do:

```
    if (mypic) { 
    mypic.hidden=YES; 
    [mypic release]; /* You need this only if you aren't using ARC */
}
```

Comment: So i need to connect it to all tabs and all pages? cant i hide it without changing all tabs?